# Is there any way in Phabricator to list number of tasks assigned to each user?

Tags: project-management, phabricator

Is there any way in Phabricator to list number of tasks assigned to each user?
Maybe some script or some plugin?
Can't find any info about this in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/report/ has basic info. You can also GROUP BY Assigned when searching in Maniphest.